# Retrieve String Containing Specific substring C#

Tags: c#, regex, string, substring

I am having an output in string format like following :

"ABCDED  0000A1.txt PQRSNT 12345"

I want to retreieve substring(s) having .txt in above string. e.g. For above it should return 0000A1.txt.

Thanks

Comment: Actually I am looking a way where I can do it using regular expressions. I am able to split string with spaces and then search substring in array/list items. Want to check if there is any short way where I can use expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split will work if it the spaces are the seperator. if you use oter seperators you can add as needed

```
 string input = "ABCDED 0000A1.txt PQRSNT 12345";
 string filename = input.Split(' ').FirstOrDefault(f => System.IO.Path.HasExtension(f));
```

filname = "0000A1.txt" and this will work for any extension

Comment: Above will not work if string contains multiple consecutive white spaces ?

Comment: @Akshay,Just tested with double and triple spaces and it works fine :)

Comment: Thanks. Instead of string.split, I can use Regex.Split also. Expression like f => System.IO.Path.HasExtension(f) is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can either split the string at whitespace boundaries like it's already been suggested or repeatedly match the same regex like this:

```
var input = "ABCDED 0000A1.txt PQRSNT 12345 THE.txt FOO";
var match = Regex.Match (input, @"\b([\w\d]+\.txt)\b");
while (match.Success) {
    Console.WriteLine ("TEST: {0}", match.Value);
    match = match.NextMatch ();
}
```

Comment: Here is the [link](http://rubular.com/r/WMoQuYEMq8) that I tried out yours. Doesn't seem to give the results... any thoughts? I am not opposed to your answer, just wondering..

Comment: Yes, you entered "klfd dfs.fd34.3jd454ADFDf98.txtdfd dlfjd".  My regex breaks on word boundaries like it's been asked for, so you need to add some whitespace between the ".txt" and the "dfd".  In addition to that, I'm also only allowing word characters and digits, no dots - you'd have to modify the regex to `\b([\w\d\.]+\.txt)\b` to also allow dots.

Comment: Or better: `\b([\w\d]+(?:\.[\w\d]+)*\.txt)\b` (must start with character or digit and may not contain two consecutive dots).

Answer (score 0):

You may use `c#`, `regex` and `pattern`, `match` :)

Here is the code, plug it in try. Please comment.

```
string test = "afdkljfljalf dkfjd.txt lkjdfjdl"; 
string ffile = Regex.Match(test, @"\([a-z0-9])+.txt").Groups[1].Value;
Console.WriteLine(ffile);
```

[Reference: regexp](http://rubular.com/r/ffiWzDyFT2)

Comment: Down-voted because you don't break on white-space boundaries: your regex would also match "ABCDED 000A1.txtFOO" and that's not what he wants.

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this:

```
string subString = "";
char period = '.';
char[] chArString;
int iSubStrIndex = 0;

if (myString != null)
{
    chArString = new char[myString.Length];
    chArString = myString.ToCharArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < myString.Length; i ++)
    {
        if (chArString[i] == period)
            iSubStrIndex = i;
    }

    substring = myString.Substring(iSubStrIndex);
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

First split your string in array using

```
char[] whitespace = new char[] { ' ', '\t' };
string[] ssizes = myStr.Split(whitespace);
```

Then find .txt in array...

```
// Find first element starting with .txt.
//
string value1 = Array.Find(array1,
    element => element.Contains(".txt", StringComparison.Ordinal));
```

Now your value1 will have the "0000A1.txt"

Happy coding.

Comment: Downvote for not reading the part where he wanted a regular expression. :)

Comment: @Vaughan Hilts, the user added that after Jigar Pandya answered, he can't predict the future :)